# Cortex-M4 timer prescaler during count up and down

Tags: timer, counter

The prescaler contains the least significant bits of the count When Counting down  and contains the most significant bits of the count when counting up.
How does the prescaler works in M4?

Comment: Yes, they are. How does your question relate to programming? Do you have an issue related to programming?

Comment: I was assuming the prescaler is always the LSB